# What is the correct signature to user to Update a Wordpress customer meta_data

Tags: woocommerce, postman

How does one update a woocommerse meta data using post man????
Tried multiple signatures all I want to do is update the meta_data of an existing user.

[Postman query to update customer's meta_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hE2H.png)

Comment: Make it object  like { "meta_data": ["key": "value"] }

Comment: still getting the same error, Is "PUT" the correct method to be using???

Comment: also tried editing the "first_name" property and i'm getting the same error. :-(